# Split rows in limited size buckets

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with thousands of records, I want to associate each row with a bucket and each bucket has a maximum of rows associated to it.

I'd love something a "bucketize" analytic function similar to ntile but that instead of the number of buckets takes the maximum number of elements of each bucket.

Is there anything like that?

```
select value, bucketize(3) as bucket
  from table;

VALUE   BUCKET
--------------
foo          1
bar          1
baz          1
qux          2
quux         2
zap          2
xfoo         3
xbar         3
xbaz         3
xqux         4
```

Comment: Question (seeing the Accepted Answer): Suppose you have 1750 rows and you want to divide them into buckets of at most 100 rows each. Do you want 17 buckets of 100 rows each and one bucket of 50 rows? Or do you want 14 buckets of 97 rows each and 4 buckets of 98 rows each? The Accepted Answer will give you the former. There are ways to get the latter (with Oracle-provided analytic functions). Then: is ordering by `value` important or desired? You can `order by null` if which rows get grouped together is irrelevant (resulting in much faster execution).

Comment: Alternatively, if you require RANDOM assignment to the buckets (there are cases when that is desired, for example in scientific or engineering experiments), then you can `order by dbms_random.value()` instead.

Comment: [width_bucket](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions234.htm#SQLRF06163) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `row_number()`:

```
select value, floor((row_number() over (order by value) - 1) / 3) as bucket
from t;
```

I don't think a separate window function is really needed in this case.

Comment: this is why I come to stackoverflow, to feel stupid everytime :)

Comment: `ceil` is the rounding-up function, which in this case would provide a simpler formula: `ceil(row_number() over (order by value) / 3)`